# How to include custom field in shortcode (do_shortcode) in theme file

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

To cut out a few steps and make it easier for authors, I have included a custom field for authors to enter details (may include HTML).

I want to add the custom field to a shortcode in the theme.

From multiple sources, I have a few sets of code, but the custom field is not displaying:

```
<?php if ( get_field('test_field') ): 
$testfield = get_field("test_field");
?>
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]'. $testfield . '[/shortcode]'); ?>   
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have also tried:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_field', true) ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]'. printf(get_post_meta($post->ID, "test_field", true)) . '[/shortcode]');
} ?>
```

I'm sure it is a simple solution, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `$test-field` is not a valid variable name. Use underscores, letters and numbers only. And that `printf()` is meaningless in this context. Enable the debug mode during development; you would have seen these errors then already.

Comment: I just changed out with example fields quickly. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed printf

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_field', true) ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]'. get_post_meta($post->ID, "test_field", true) . '[/shortcode]');
} ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the solution as well as post the code?